# Javascript Regex - remove only first 0 digit in string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript string containing chars and digits. Now, if the string contains a sequence of (arabic-only) numbers, e.g.

`Mr. Bond is agent 0070`,

I want to remove the very first zero in it:

RESULT:  `Mr. Bond is agent 070`.

Other zeros coming after non-zero digits shouldnt be removed.

My solution in regex-php-flavour is `/[[^\]]*?\K0/` which works flawless.

Unfortunately, Javascript doesn't support the backslash K feature (\K) php has.

Comment: You just need `s=s.replace("0", "")`, no need for a regex.  In PHP, to remove the first `0` , you may use `$s = preg_replace('~0~', '', $s, 1);`

Comment: Are you saying that if the string is `XYZ 700`, it _shouldn't_ be transformed to `XYZ 70`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this regex `/0\d+/` and pass a callback to render your result.

```js
var str = "Mr. Bond is agent 0070";

str = str.replace(/0\d+/, function(t) {
  return t.substring(1);
});

console.log(str)
```

You can capture the group `&1` as  [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew) mentioned, this is the straightforward/cleanest solution.

```js
var str = "Mr. Bond is agent 0070".replace(/0(\d+)/, "$1");

console.log(str)
```

Comment: Your solution is basically `str = str.replace(/0(\d+)/, "$1");`

Comment: Why not go for the much simpler `replace` function as Wiktor has mentioned?

Comment: @Tyler The above will also handle `Mr. Bond is agent 0 0070`

Comment: @Tyler It'll turn `700` into `70`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you're right, I forgot the grouping result.  I'm going to mention that.

Comment: Oh, that is quite confusing. X D

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you! answer updated!

Comment: Thanks Ele, doing your way. What a lovely place Stackoverflow is solving ours of headaches within minutes